# Interact.js draggables not visible when dragging out of a dropzone with overflow:scroll

Tags: overflow, interact.js

I'm building an interact.js app with two dropzones. One begins with all of the draggables in it and is scrollable. When dragging out of the origin dropzone, the draggables become hidden.

I've tried all of the suggested methods such as setting `overflow: visible` and `position: absolute` on the draggables. I've also tried almost every possible combination of z-indexes that could possibly make sense.

Here's a JSfiddle with the problem re-created: http://jsfiddle.net/L5g9prao/1/

- Expected behaviour: Draggables stay visible when dragging between dropzones
- Actual behaviour: Draggables become hidden as the leave the origin dropzone.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to apply `position: fixed` and a `top` position to the draggable for the `onstart` event like so:

```
onstart(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    let position = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    target.style.position = "fixed";
    target.style.top = position.top + "px";
}
```

And then in my use case, the draggable is deleted and cloned so I don't have to remove those properties, but if you need to, do so in the `onend` function like so:

```
onend(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    target.style.position = "relative";
    target.style.top = "auto";
}
```

Thanks to @marcdubs for the [answer](https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/687#issuecomment-453334265)